# Изменение заднего фона в зависимости от выбранного изображения

Tags: javascript, css3, анимация, css-animation

Необходимо, чтобы при загрузке изображения это же изображение появлялось размытым на заднем фоне.

Есть ли такая функция в AngularJS ? Или отдельный плагин?
 Подскажите пожалуйста, каким способом это реализовать.

[image: bg-like-pic]

Comment: тут просто версткой `css blur`

Comment: Основной вопрос заключается в том, как добавить в фон выбранное изображение?

Comment: По-русски мы не говорим "задний фон" (как, например, и "верхний потолок", "отличное отличие", и т.п.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в разметку элемент фона, а изображению - слушателя события `load`... и просто устанавливайте свойство `background-image` этому элементу фона.
Позиция, размытие, и прочее  - это всего несколько строк на CSS.

```js
const IMAGE_SOURCES = [
  'http://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone_1047724.jpg?width=90', 
  'http://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone_1045590.jpg?width=90', 
  'http://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone_1046545.jpg?width=90', 
  'http://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone_841470.jpg?width=90', 
  'http://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone_1027311.jpg?width=90'
]; 

var srcGen = imageSrcGenerator(IMAGE_SOURCES),
    bgEl   = document.getElementById('background'), 
    imgEl  = document.getElementById('pic'); 

imgEl.addEventListener('load', function () {
  bgEl.style.backgroundImage = `url(${this.src})`; 
}); 
imgEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.src = srcGen.next().value; 
}); 
imgEl.click(); 

function* imageSrcGenerator(srcArr) {
  let i = -1;
  while (++i < srcArr.length || !(i = 0))
    yield srcArr[i]; 
}
```

```css
#background {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center 30%; 
  background-size: cover; 
  filter: blur(8px);
}

#pic {
  width: 90px; height: 130px; 
  position: absolute; left: 20%; top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 #0004; 
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<img id="pic">
```

Если  захотите избавиться от полупрозрачных краев (которые образуются при размытии фонового изображения) - позиционируйте элемент фона таким образом, чтобы он этими краями вылезал за границы родителя (которому, конечно же, нужно будет назначить стили `overflow: hidden` и `position: absolute`). То есть, просто задайте отрицательные значения (равные радиусу размытия) CSS-свойствам `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, и оберните элемент в еще один блок.

Answer (score 2):

Например так, второй картинкой, смотрим:

```css
.card {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.blurry {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #666;
}

.blurry img {
  position: absolute;
  filter: blur(10px);
  width: 110%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: .5;
}

.cover {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.cover img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="blurry"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdEEpCwzpA4E6GBOn693lsyIVdrlCcK8Y_OAEt8T7-3JKdp152ow"></div>
  <div class="cover"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdEEpCwzpA4E6GBOn693lsyIVdrlCcK8Y_OAEt8T7-3JKdp152ow"></div>
</div>
```

соответственно вставляете в angularjs так-же с `ng-src`